# How to make smooth opening blocks? (on js)

Tags: javascript, css

I have a container with images and a "load more" button to add more images. It works, but I want to make a smooth opening from top to bottom, but I fail. I added 'opacity' to see it works, but still, 'transition' doesn't happen. I looked at other people's examples, where the code works using the height of the container, but I add the number of images, I want to add 6 images and smoothly. How can do this correctly?

```js
let data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block .item')),
    step = 6,
    item = 0;

data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
item += step;
  
document.querySelector('#load').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
  tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
  item += step;
  let animation = document.querySelector('.block');
  animation.classList.add('fade');
  
  if(tmp.length < 6){
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.item {
  background-color: #6ab7eb;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 }
 
 #load {
  background-color: white;
 }
 
 .block.fade {
  -webkit-transition: height .5s ease;
  -o-transition: height .5s ease;
  transition: height .5s ease;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<button id="load">Load more</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**here is a snippet it may help you:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $(".block .item").size();
    x=0;
    $('.block li:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+6 : size_li;
        $('.block .item:lt('+x+')').addClass('show');
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
.block{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.item{
   background-color: #6ab7eb;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block .item{ 
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.block .item.show {
  height: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

Comment: Any reason **you're not putting your code *here* and explaining your approach**?

Comment: It would be better if I put it in something like jsfiddle to be more  organized and clear . what is the problem in that?

Comment: I'm not interested in JQuery approach, I can do that. I am interested in the implementation in pure javascript. Thanks.

Comment: @OmarM.Fathy What makes you think forcing people to navigate away from StackOverflow and the question would in any way be "more organized and clear"? The opposite is true.

Comment: @connexo You are right, I edited my answer, and thank you for telling me this, I will avoid it in the future